# Pagination and storing into database

Tags: php, mysql

Hi all I want to create question and answer with pagination, after clicking the next button first page should validate and store in database and will go to next page? i tried some code but i have no idea how to post the value and store into database with pagination.

**my code is**

```
<form class="cmxform" id="form1" method="get" action="process.php" >
$newsquestion=$db->paging("SELECT * FROM question where classname='$_SESSION[class_name]' and category in (select category from cat where class_name='$_SESSION[class_name]' order by p_order) and  status='1'",1);
foreach($newquestion as question)
{
$answer=$db->get_results("SELECT * FROM answer where qid='$question->id'");
foreach($newanswer as $answer)
         {
<input type="radio" name='answer_value1[<?php echo $question->id?>]' value="<?php echo$answer->id?>" validate="required:true" />

}
Comment :<textarea  rows="5" cols="50" name="comment[<?php echo $question->id?>]" validate="required:true'" ></textarea>
```

}

and in pagination field i put

```
$linktext.=" <a href='$nextlnk' title='Show Next ".$this->MaxRecord." Data'><input type='Submit' name='button' value='Submit' ></a>";
```

How can i store the question value in database.

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use PHP you can add the following after having updated your mysql database to redirect the user to the next page:

```
header("Location: $nextlnk");
```

Then all you need is a submit button that says "Next" that will both post the answer and push the user forward to the next question.

Comment: I tried but it wont shows next question it still shows the same first question i put this link in "process.php" after adding the question and answer to the database. my code is like this : header("Location: srv_form.php?$nextlnk");

Comment: And you're sure you have something in the `srv_form.php`script to catch your `$nextlnk`variable? You should probably do: `header("Location: srv_form.php?next=$nextlnk");` and then catch the `next`variable like this: `if isset($_GET['next'])` to initiate the next question based on the value stored in that index...

Comment: this $nextlnk variable is get from another file i tried to print in the srv_form.php but it wont display the variable value. my code store in another php file and function is like this function getnewLink($linkfor=0){$nextlnk=$oldPage."&cp=".$NextPage;} i called the link function in srv_form.php is "echo $db->getnewLink();  " but i tried to call the $nextlink variable value into the srv_form.php, i cannot. please guide me.

Comment: did you remember to include the php-file in which you have defined the variable that you wish to use before you use it? `include("otherfile.php")` or `require_once("otherfile.php")`

Comment: I'm not sure why you call an `echo`function. It seems to me you should be doing something along these lines: `header("Location: srv_form.php?".$db->getnewLink());`

Comment: thank you for your great support i do some tricks to do that i just pass the variable to the next page and increase by 1 and redirect as ?page=$increase values. so it works now. thank you